# I want to put Php Function using Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am using php and javascript on my code.

When i select the photo. I am showing picture's details with javascript.
Now, its working but i get data with javascript, when i showing the photo size its showing like '339.827 KB'. i dont want to like this.

I have php function. it is converting byte to megabyte. How can i use javascript with php function.

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#openFile').on('change', function (evt) {
            document.getElementById('fileName').innerHTML = this.files[0].name;
            document.getElementById('fileSize').innerHTML = ((this.files[0].size / 1024)).toFixed(4) + " KB";  // this area
            document.getElementById('fileType').innerHTML = this.files[0].type;

            var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

            if (this.files[0].name.match(/\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$/)) {
                var image, file;
                if ((file = this.files[0])) {
                    image = new Image();
                    image.onload = function () {
                        var resolution = this.width + " x " + this.height;
                        document.getElementById('imageResolution').innerHTML = resolution;
                    };
                    image.src = _URL.createObjectURL(file);
                }
            } else {
                document.getElementById('imageResolution').innerHTML = "";
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php function byte_Format($size, $decimals = 0){
$unit = array(
    '0' => 'Byte',
    '1' => 'Kb',
    '2' => 'Mb',
    '3' => 'Gb',
    '4' => 'Tb',
    '5' => 'Pb',
    '6' => 'Eb',
    '7' => 'Zb',
    '8' => 'Yb'
);

for($i = 0; $size >= 1024 && $i <= count($unit); $i++){
    $size = $size/1024;
}

return round($size, $decimals).' '.$unit[$i];


} ?>
```

I want to achieve the 
->`document.getElementById('fileSize').innerHTML = <?php byte_Format(size,2); ?>`

Note: The "size" coming from javascript in byte_Format function.

Comment: Why not just rewrite that PHP function in JS?

Comment: Its a bad programming...you can put other prog languages functions iff it is not available in JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you cannot call `php function` inside your `javascript` because `PHP` is completely executed on server side and `javascript` is purely in your browser. You can do this thing by using ajax. You can pass your variable via ajax to server side, where php can convert your byte to megabyte and return you back.

Secondly you can rewrite php function into javascript, which is not difficult as such from where I can see. I have converted it to javascript and pasted below for you:

```
<script>
    function byte_Format($size, $decimals)
    {
        $size = parseFloat($size);
        $decimals = $decimals || 0;
        var $unit = ['Byte','Kb','Mb','Gb','Tb','Pb','Eb','Zb','Yb'];

        for($i = 0; $size >= 1024 && $i <= $unit.length; $i++){
            $size = $size/1024;
        }

        return $size.toFixed($decimals) + ' ' + $unit[$i];
    }
</script>
```

Now you can achieve it like : ->`document.getElementById('fileSize').innerHTML = byte_Format(size,2);`

Comment: As a matter of Javascript style you should remove the $ signs before the variable names.